# How to make IE remember login details?

Tags: internet-explorer, authentication, autocomplete

For some odd reason IE no longer will remember previously typed in usernames/passwords on our login screen.  IE8 will remember the username only and then the password still needs to be typed in, but IE6 and IE7 don't fill in either.  And of course it works fine in Firefox/Chrome/Safari/etc.

(And yes, I've already checked my preferences and they are set correctly.)

Is there something specific on an `<input>` or the `<form>` itself that triggers IE to prompt the user to remember the login details?

Comment: It might be a bit obvious, but if you're using Source control, have you diff'd back a bit to see if that identfies anything? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the login page sent out over HTTPS? That would prevent login information from saving.

Comment: Also, do you know anywhere in particular that states this? I need some "proof" to show to some people about this.

Comment: [Comment at the end of this article][1]


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533486(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I guess the article syntax for linking doesn't work in comments. ><

Answer (score 1):

is [autocomplete="off"](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion) set on the form?

[MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533486(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Nope, everything is pretty normal on the forms. It used to remember the details but I can't figure out what changed.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of - has someone pressed "don't prompt to remember passwords again" lately ?

I actually think there *may* be a non standard attribute to disable the automatic remembering of the password. But this seems to be the inverse of what you want.